# Importing an AWS image into softlayer

Tags: amazon-web-services, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

Is it possible to import an AWS image into softlayer directly? I know we can download AWS image and the import into softlayer but was looking for some automated solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is not any Softlayer's API method wich make all the proccess automatically, the image must be uploaded in any of your object storage's account you could use the API to upload the image there here some references:

http://sldn.softlayer.com/blog/waelriac/Managing-SoftLayer-Object-Storage-Through-REST-APIs

and see this documentation about how to handle large files

https://docs.openstack.org/developer/swift/overview_large_objects.html

Once the file has been uploaded tou can import it using the API:

here an example using the SOftlayer's Python client:

```
"""
Create Image Template from external source

This script creates a transaction to import a disk image from an external source and create 
a standard image template

Important manual pages:
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest_Block_Device_Template_Group/createFromExternalSource
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Container_Virtual_Guest_Block_Device_Template_Configuration
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest_Block_Device_Template_Group

License: http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/License
Author: SoftLayer Technologies, Inc. <sldn@softlayer.com>
"""
import SoftLayer

# Your SoftLayer username and apiKey
USERNAME = 'set me'
API_KEY = 'set me'

# Declare the group name to be applied to the imported template
name = 'imageTemplateTest'
# Declare the note to be applied to the imported template
note = 'This is for test Rcv'

'''
Declare referenceCode of the operating system software description for the imported VHD
available options: CENTOS_6_32, CENTOS_6_64, CENTOS_7_64, REDHAT_6_32, REDHAT_6_64, REDHAT_7_64, 
UBUNTU_12_32, UBUNTU_12_64, UBUNTU_14_32, UBUNTU_14_64, WIN_2003-STD-SP2-5_32, WIN_2003-STD-SP2-5_64, 
WIN_2008-STD-R2-SP1_64, WIN_2012-STD_64.
'''
operatingSystemReferenceCode = 'CENTOS_6_64'

'''
Define the parameters below, which refers to object storage where the image template is stored. 
It will help to build the uri.
'''
# Declare the object storage account name
objectStorageAccountName = 'SLOS307608-10'
# Declare the cluster name where the image is stored
clusterName = 'dal05'
# Declare the container name where the image is stored
containerName = 'OS'
# Declare the file name of the image stored in the object storage, it should be .vhd or 
fileName = 'testImage2.vhd-0.vhd'

"""
Creating an SoftLayer_Container_Virtual_Guest_block_Device_Template_Configuration Skeleton
which contains the information from external source
"""
configuration = {
    'name': name,
    'note': note,
    'operatingSystemReferenceCode': operatingSystemReferenceCode,
    'uri': 'swift://'+ objectStorageAccountName + '@' + clusterName + '/' + containerName + '/' + fileName
}

# Declare the API client
client = SoftLayer.Client(username=USERNAME, api_key=API_KEY)
groupService = client['SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest_Block_Device_Template_Group']

try:
    result = groupService.createFromExternalSource(configuration)
    print(result)
except SoftLayer.SoftLayerAPIError as e:
    print("Unable to create the image template from external source. faultCode=%s, faultString=%s" % (e.faultCode, e.faultString))
    exit(1)
```

Regards

Comment: Ok but there is no method to refer amazon AMIs directly from an Softlayer account and import them in Softlayer?

Comment: As i sad in my answer "there is not any Softlayer's API method wich make all the proccess automatically".